Is there a way to programatically register apps on Microsoft Entra ID on the fly in C#?
Basically, is there a way to programmatically do
this.
I have tried this, but even for this you need to register an app manually first.
This is very easy to do in powershell with
az ad app create --display-name "test-app"

and I was just wondering if there was any way I could "impersonate" azure cli in C# to accomplish this in C#

The Graph API link doesn't say you need to register an app manually. The client will have to authenticate first. The command line tools use the APIs as well. In fact, you could use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to see what they actually call

To create a Microsoft Entra ID application, check the below`:
Login to az, using az login:

And make use of below code:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;

namespace AzureADAppCreation
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(credential);
            var newApp = new Application
            {
                DisplayName = "RukAppCsharp"
            };

            try
            {
                var createdApp = await graphClient.Applications.PostAsync(newApp);


                Console.WriteLine("Azure AD App created successfully:");
                Console.WriteLine($"App ID: {createdApp.AppId}");
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error creating Azure AD App: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}


The Microsoft Entra ID application created successfully like below:

